# C# Hashtable Internal datastructure

Tags: c#, data-structures

All -

Asking a specific question which I came across recently and surprisingly didn't find any convincing answer.

What is the internal backing data structure which C# Hashtable (and Dictionary - which internally uses Hashtable) leverages

So in essence - what kind of buckets are key value pairs stored in - ArrayList, LinkedList (which I know is not the answer here), tree structure etc.

Not looking for collision strategies etc - simply once a hashcode is computed - what data structure does Hashtable internally use to store this value?

Any explanation or article pointers will really help.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Jon that is an awesome link.

Comment: Thanks Jon - I re-read the article right now - still doesnt help me understand the backing datastructure. It even says this -  realize that expanding the Hashtable is not an inexpensive operation. Makes me think its more like an ArrayList - but msdn doesnt say this explicitly - which is a bummer !!!!

Comment: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Hashtable@cs/1305376/Hashtable@cs

Comment: I believe in both cases the buckets are just stored in arrays.

Comment: Agree - thats the general sense I get from all the stuff I have read - was just surpised - no MSDN article calls it out explictly. Thanks a lot though

Comment: I think it just uses `T[]` for the buckets. ArrayList would be an odd choice since it doesn't use generics while Dictionary and HashTable do.

Comment: "No MSDN article calls it out explicitly." Any particular reason it should?

Comment: No - I was just curious why the information was not explicit. Not questioning anybody's intent here - but felt this was something common/obvious which would be in writing. People may disagree - but my take on it. Really appreciate the answers here though

Comment: I just double checked. It is mostly a simple array of buckets. When you insert enough entries that it exceeds the load factor, it double the size of the buckets array and rehashes everything to the new buckets array -- The doubling is modified by making sure the number of buckets is actually a prime number. I confirmed this using RedGates reflector.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a nice explanation of dictionary internal datastructure:
https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/09/16/the-net-dictionary/ , the same is thrue for HashTable

In a nutshell
hashtable consists of two arrays: buckets and entries

When adding an item, the hash code is generated modulo the current array size, and that determines the slot the item is stored in.

However, that slot is not the one in entries, it is actually the one in buckets.

The value in buckets at the hashed index is then the index of the slot in entries that the data is actually stored at, and that is simply assigned to the next free slot in the array.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 3):

`System.Collections.Hashtable` defines a custom struct (bucket) for storing the key, value and collision information and keeps a simple array of instances of that struct.

`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary` uses about the same strategy, although with generic types instead of `object`. The generic `Dictionary` does not make use of the non-generic `Hashtable`, even though they work similarly.

Comment: Thats an interesting comment - Dictionary (which is based of Generics) does not make use of non-generic Hashtable.  I thought it internally does use Hashtable (the non-generic version)

Comment: Another difference between the `Hashtable` and `Dictionary` types is their collision resolution strategy. While `Hashtable` uses *rehashing/double hashing*, `Dictionary` uses the *chaining* technique.